# Global assumption for unit trace

Tags: assumptions

I am specifying a general two-dimensional density matrix:

```
ρ1 = {{Abs[α]^2, α*Conjugate[β]}, {Conjugate[α]*β, Abs[β]^2}};
```

I want Mathematica to recognise that the trace of the above matrix is 1. How do I specify a global assumption for this? I tried looking up the appropriate syntax of `$Assumptions`, but could not find anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the density matrix is defined as

```
m[a_, b_] := {{Abs[a]^2, a Conjugate[b]}, {Conjugate[a] b, Abs[b]^2}}
```

then it is possible to define an [`UpValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) for symbol `m`, using [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpSetDelayed.html):

```
Trace[m[a_, b_]] ^:= 1
```

Now, simply evaluating

```
Trace[m[a,b]]
```

produces

> ```
> 1
> ```

Also, evaluating something like `3.1 Trace[m[x,y]] + 0.1` evaluates to `3.2` as expected.

Comment: Thanks! I had one more doubt. In case I specify the normalisation condition directly `Abs[a]^2+Abs[b]^2 ^:=1`, Mathematica gives a message which says that tag power is protected. Why does this happen?

Comment: assuming `h[x]` stands for a valid expression in `x`, `f[x_]:=h[x]` associates the *rhs* with the symbol `f` (see [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html)); on the other hand, `f[g[x_]]^:=h[x]` associates `h[x]` with symbol `g` (**not** `f` as one might expect-that's an `UpValue` for `g`); evaluate `Abs[a]^2 + Abs[b]^2 // FullForm`; verify that `Power` is placed where `g` is in the example above; `Power` has attribute `Protected` which doesn't allow altering the rules defined for it; using`Trace` might be a better choice